# Google IoT - not able to enable IoT API

Tags: iot

I am new to google iot Cloud. While i am trying to enable Cloud IoT API i get the below error
Enable services: cloudiot.googleapis.com,pubsub
15 minutes ago
iotsample
Bind permission denied for service: cloudiot.googleapis.com Service cloudiot.googleapis.com is not
available to this consumer

Could some one guid me how to enable the API

Tried enabling From IoT Cloudshell
but error:

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:

  - subject: ?error_code=110002&service=servicemanagement.googleapis.com&permission=servicemanagement.services.bind&resource=XXXXXXXX
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  metadata:
  permission: servicemanagement.services.bind
  resource: XXXXXXXX
  service: servicemanagement.googleapis.com
  reason: AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED

Comment: GCP IoT Core is deprecated and will be terminated in august. Apparently they prevent us from enabling the feature in newly created environment. There might be a way to ask then to whitelist our project to allow IoT Core. 
While this might be best to avoid creating new feature using IoT Core, this is a big concern as it makes impossible to replicate your environment for testing patches if you still support Iot Core.